# How can I user SpEl to sort a Collection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a List that I want to sort using a spring expression. I am currently using a Comparator and a TreeSet whereby the Comparator takes a spring expression and compares the result of parsing that spring expression on each member of the list.

It probably works (I haven't tested it yet), I gusted wanted to find out if anybody knew of a better way.

This is what I currently have for the Comparator. :

```
public class SpringElComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
    private static ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    private static Map<String, Expression> expCache = new HashMap<>();

    private Expression exp;

    public SpringELRule(String expression) {
        exp = expCache.get(expression);
        if(exp == null) {
            exp = new Expression(expression);
            expCache.put(expression, exp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Object c1 = exp.getValue(o1);
        Object c2 = exp.getValue(o2);
        int result;
        if (c1 instanceof Comparator) {
            Comparator comparator1 = (Comparator)c1;
            Comparator comparator2 = (Comparator)c2;
             result = comparator1.compare(comparator2);
        } else if (c1 instanceof Comparable) {
            Comparable comparable1 = (Comparable)c1;
            Comparable comparable2 = (Comparable)c2;
            result = comparable1.compareTo(comparable2);
        }

        if(result == 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is a better fit for this question.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not after a code review, I'm after a better way if there is one.

Comment: One thing that gets my attention is `if (result == 0) return -1`. So if they're equal `o1` is less? So in a sense two instances are **never** equal. Why not only return `result`?